# MVC 5 Identity 2.0 display profile completion at login

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

Using MVC 5 and Identity 2.0, I add custom properties to `ApplicationUserClass` like `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Address`. Those will be new fields in the database. When the user register to the application he/she will enter the email address and password only. After they register, and they log in I want to force them to complete their profile, or at least each time they login they should be redirected to the profile completion page where they can mention the FirstName, Lastname and Address. Afther they complete the profile they will not be redirected to complete profile page each time they login.

Something like:

```
if UserProfile != Completed

   go to CompleteProfilePage

else

   go to MainPage
```

Comment: I was thinking maybe a custom filter will work as I need to implement this globally in the application no matter what page user goes to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try a global filter. This will not allow your users to bypass the check by modifying the URL manually.

```
public class ProfileCompletionCheckAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        //this will prevent redirect for still unauthenticated users
        if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            return;

        //replace these to actual values of your profile completion action and controller
        string actionOfProfilePage = "Index";
        string controlerOfProfilePage = "Home";

        bool areWeAlreadyInProfilePage = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ActionName == actionOfProfilePage
            && filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.ControllerName == controlerOfProfilePage;

        if (areWeAlreadyInProfilePage) //this will prevent redirect loop
            return;

        bool isProfileComplete = false; //replace this with your custom logic

        if (!isProfileComplete)
        {                
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary 
                { 
                    { "controller", controlerOfProfilePage }, 
                    { "action", actionOfProfilePage } 
                });
        }
    }
}
```

To enable it, just add this to FilterConfig.cs

`filters.Add(new ProfileCompletionCheckAttribute());`

Comment: So basically I have to get the current user and then check each property if contains data and set isProfileComplete accordingly, correct?

Answer (score 0):

In your **AccountController** something like this :

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{

    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {
        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
    }


    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```

Upgrade like this

```
//
// POST: /Account/Login

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Login(LoginModel model, string returnUrl)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid && WebSecurity.Login(model.UserName, model.Password, persistCookie: model.RememberMe))
    {

        UsersContext dbu = new UsersContext();
        UserProfile usr = dbu.UserProfiles.Where(u => u.UserName == model.UserName).First();

        if (usr.FirstName == null) return RedirectToAction("Profile", "Account");

        return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);

    }

    // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
    return View(model);
}
```